# Building .exe file with database connectivity jars

Tags: java, swing, launch4j, antbuilder

Can anyone tell me how to build the .exe file by including the library jar files for database connection? I have a standalone application and I am using the launch 4j .exe builder.

Answer (score 1):

jar to exe possible for database connection also.
but you always refer the absolute path for any files,jars and anything.
because exe run anywhere in windows.
   For example : if your exe have any file association.
so you must select a constant path there you put your all jars and needed files.
In your coding refer that file using the constant absolute path.
   For example :  **c:\Program files\your company\your product;**   **c:\Program files\your company\your product\your jars** and like this. your classpath refer this jars. so your exe run without any relative path problem.  if you use any installer your work is very easy. example **Advanced Installer.**

Answer (score 0):

```
Let the distribution file structure is like this:

bin/launch4j.exe  
bin/config.xml  
bin/dist/app.jar  
bin/dist/lib/ojdbc6.jar

jar files in the lib directory can be included in the config file as below:

<launch4jConfig>
  ...........
  <chdir>./dist</chdir>
  ...........
  <classPath>
    ..........
    <cp>./lib/*.jar</cp>
    ..........
  </classPath>
  ...........
</launch4jConfig>
```